# Is there anyway to arrange plots using par () function?

Tags: r

I have created 3 rows with 3 figures each and would like to centre the last 2 figures to achieve visual representativity since they are aligned to the left side of my multiple plot. Is there any way of doing that without modifying the size of the graphs?

```
dat=read.csv("r1new.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec="."); dat
par(mfrow=c(4,3))
par(mar=c(4,4,2,2))
############################################### WC 0.1 ###############################################
res.lm1 = lm(dat$wc_10_1~dat$m_wc_10_1, data=dat)
res.lm2 = lm(dat$wc_10_3~dat$m_wc_10_3, data=dat)
res.lm3 = lm(dat$wc_10_5~dat$m_wc_10_5, data=dat)
res.res1 = resid(res.lm1)
res.res2 = resid(res.lm2)
res.res3 = resid(res.lm3)
plot(dat$m_wc_10_1 [1:1731], res.res1, 
      ylab="Residuals", 
      xlab="modelled water content, 0.1 m", 
      main="",
      xlim=c(0.05,0.55), ylim=c(-0.25,0.15),
      type="p",
      col="blue",
      pch=16) 
points(dat$m_wc_10_3 [1:814],res.res2, col="green3",pch=16)
points(dat$m_wc_10_5 [1:1768],res.res3, col="red",pch=16)
abline(0, 0, col="gold3", lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out `layout`. You need to define a matrix that shows the order and placement of graphs. Then these are filled in according to number. I believe the following example is approximately what you are looking for:

```
M <- matrix(rep(1:12, each = 2), nrow = 4, ncol = 3*2, byrow = T)
M[4,] <- c(0,10,10,11,11,0)
M

png("testplot.png", width = 6, height = 7, units = "in", res = 200)
layout(M)
layout.show(11)
op <- par(mar = c(3,3,0.5,0.5))
for(i in seq(11)){
  plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
}
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]